# user_id as custom dimension not passing to GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I've created a custom dimension to pass the user-_id (a shopify customer id) to a custom report in GA, however it's not populating. Steps I've taken:
1. Defined custom dimension in GA called "User ID" with scope User
2. Configured in Tag Manager in page view tag, a new variable to capture the user_id from the data layer.
Following is a screenshot from the Tag manager assistant:
[image]

3. Creating a custom report with this new dimension and other metrics

Any idea why it's not passing the data?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are firing that code ? Looks like GTAG.js syntax, not GTM.
How are you sure that the user_id value isn't being sent ??
Try with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom

Comment: You are using the GA native user_id field, not a Custom Dimension, then it doesn't show up as a Custom Dimension in your reports. However, the native user_id is used by GA for its user centric processing, but not available in reports, except User Explorer.

Comment: It's a custom dimension in my GA, index 9.  Then I added in the google tag manager a data layer variable with the custom dimension index 9.

Comment: I see my data layer push as follows:
Arguments(3)
callee: (...)
0: "config"
1: "UA-102855209-1"
2:
linker: {domains: Array(5)}
anonymize_ip: true
allow_ad_personalization_signals: true
currency: "USD"
link_attribution: true
optimize_id: undefined
page_referrer: null
send_page_view: false
user_id: "6823249287"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()
get callee: ƒ ()
set callee: ƒ ()
__proto__: Object

How do I connect this to the data layer variable?

Comment: Are you running GTAG.js or GTM ?
Adding a gtag.js in a Custom HTML tag in GTM ?
How do you push those values ?
To map a GTM variable to the "user_id" dataLayer variable you declare a new Variable in GTM and set the type as DataLayer and the source value as 'user_id'

Comment: running GTM and created the variable as you mentioned - DataLayer type with value 'user_id'. I guess I have an issue with the push - any idea how I can push it from shopify? This is the code I have in the liquid theme:
{% if customer.id %}<script>
  $(window).ready(function() {
    $('head script[async][src*="analytics"]').on('load', function() {
      dataLayer = [{
  'user_id': '{{customer.id}}'
   }];
    });
  });
</script>{% endif %}
is this correct?

Comment: it looks pretty ugly ! never overwrite the dataLayer variable !
Just do .push to pass new values, like: <script> window.dataLayer.push({ 'user_id': '{{customer.id}}' }); </script>

Comment: ok thx I changed it and I see that it pushed it into the data layer using GTM assistant. Also defined the custom dimension and variable in GTM with dimension 9 and data layer value "user_id". Is there anything else to configure or should it start flowing now?

Comment: Good ! Maybe use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom to check that the value is flowing into to the dimension9 slot of your GA hit ?
Tag Assistant should show it too, you need to drill down..

Comment: I see it's in the data layer but nothing happens in GA

Comment: Did you add the mapping in GTM as described below ? If you don't pass the value from the dataLayer to GA, it will not get there by magic. Which type of GA tag do you use ? Without detailed description of what you do, we can't help.

Comment: Yes I have defined a custom dimension in GA called "User ID" on the session level and the index is 9. Then in GTM I have added in google analytics: universal analytics tag a data layer variable configured to capture "user_id" into custom dimension index 9.
I do have other custom dimensions that work but they are javascript variables not data variables. Then finally I've configured in my shopify <script> window.dataLayer.push({ 'user_id': '{{customer.id}}' }); </script> in the theme liquid. Does this capture all the correct actions?

Comment: Sounds like you're only missing the proper 'timing'. You should use GTM debug mode to check at every Event (on the left column) what is the value (use the tab at the top) of the user_id variable. It's likely your GA tag fires too early and that the value isn't set yet.
You need to adjust the trigger of the GA page vue to match at least the moment where data is pushed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the value to Google Analytics as custom dimension.

So, you have to add the index of the custom dimension and its value in '**Custom Dimensions**' field in the Google Analytics tags or its shared settings variable:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have it as a custom dimension.